# How to package .NET application for veracode scanning

Tags: static-analysis, veracode

I am using VeraCode for the first time. I have ASP.NET MVC application .NET 4.7.2. To analyze ASP.NET applications, Veracode requires you to supply all the forms the application uses and all the dependencies in the compiled form, which are the DLL, EXE, and PDB files.

I used VeraCode's `Veracode Static for Visual Studio` extension to build application using VeraCode settings. I could upload application for scanning directly using Veracode Extension menu. However this extension uploads one file at a time and extension is very buggy. Every now and then upload just stops in the middle and I have to start all over again.

What's the best way to package DLL,PDB, JS files. By default The compiled assets are deployed in `\PrecompiledWeb` folder

1> Can I zip of the entire folder `\PrecompiledWeb` and upload for scanning? This folder will have other assets as well, like .json, web.config files.

2> Or Do I manually need to create zip of (DLL & PDB) and another zip of only JS files

3> Do I also need to include `.compiled` files?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you can zip the file. It uploads faster. Its okay to have other
   assets there, If Veracode supports it, it will scan it.
2. No, One zip is fine for all files.
3. No. '.compiled' is not mentioned on there help page. [This](https://help.veracode.com/r/compilation_net) says:

> Applications must be packaged as EXE, DLL, NUPKG, or ZIP files. Veracode requires debug symbols (PDB files) to be included with the application to accurately report the filenames and line numbers for findings.

And for JS files. See [this](https://help.veracode.com/r/compilation_jscript).

I have done a scan with exe, dll, pdb, js, css, html all in one zip. It works.

Comment: So I have to exclude .compiled files? When veracode compile the project, each view is compiled into DLL and it also creates `.compiled` file

Comment: Yes, probably. The links have no mention of .compiled files